# Guardar .txt con datos ordenados

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un código en el que tengo varias listas y los valores de estas listas los guardo en un archivo txt. El problema es que cuando lo paso a .txt me gustarían que estuviesen alineados por filas y columnas y no sé como realizar esto. Como el código que tengo es amplio, pongo un ejemplo de lo que busco:

```
Cabecera=["Nombre","Apellidos","DNI"]
Lista3=["María del Carmen","Perez Rivas","00000000A"]
Lista4=["Raquel","Gonzalez Perez","00000000B"]
Lista5=["Juan Francisco","Luis Hernandez","00000000C"]
Lista6=["Francisco","Gomez Palenzuela","00000000D"]
```

Y al exportarlo en un .txt me gustaría que se viese de esta forma (lo estoy haciendo a mano, pero se entiende la idea de cómo lo quiero ordenado):

```
     Nombre               Apellidos               DNI
María del Carmen         Perez Rivas           00000000A
Raquel                 Gonzalez Perez          00000000B
Juan Francisco         Luis Hernandez          00000000C
Francisco             Gomez Palenzuela         00000000D
```

No obstante, cuando escribo en el fichero txt sale sin esta estructura:

```
Nombre  Apellidos   DNI
María del Carmen Perez Rivas   0000000A
Raquel  Gonzalez Perez    00000000B
Juan Francisco  Luis Hernandez  00000000C
Francisco Gomez Palenzuela   00000000D
```

Hasta ahora he pensado en ir añadiendo espacios, pero esto es muy laborioso, además de que si añado más elementos a la lista en medio de los que ya tengo como podría ser:

```
Cabecera=["Nombre","Apellidos", "Direccion","DNI"]
```

se me descuadraría todo.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto de forma óptima?

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esté código calcula el ancho máximo por columna:

```
max_ancho = [0] * len(Cabecera)
for contenido in [Cabecera, Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    for idx in range(len(contenido)):
        max_ancho[idx] = max(max_ancho[idx], len(contenido[idx]))
print(max_ancho)
```

Toma la lista `Cabecera` para obtener el número de columnas a imprimir. La lista `max_ancho` guarda el ancho máximo por columna.

El `for` recorre cada lista y va actualizando el máximo ancho de cada columna, produciendo:

```
print(max_ancho) => [16, 16, 9]
```

Con esta información puedo imprimir la cabecera, centrando cada título en su respectiva columna:

```
linea = [f"{Cabecera[0]:^{max_ancho[0]}}",
         f"{Cabecera[1]:^{max_ancho[1]}}",
         f"{Cabecera[2]:^{max_ancho[2]}}"]
print(' '.join(linea))
```

El truco está en utilizar las capacidades de formateo de los *f-string*. Aqui utilizamos el siguiente formato:

```
f"{valor}:{caracter de ajuste}{ancho}"
```

El valor es `Cabecera[col]` y el ancho destinado a la salida es `max_ancho[col]`. Si el string es menor a ese largo, se ajusta según el caracter indicado:

- `"^"` centrado.
- `"<"` ajuste al margen izquierdo.
- `">"` ajuste al margen derecho.

Para imprimir las líneas de datos es la misma cosa; sólo cambian los ajustes: derecha para la primera columna, centrado por la segunda, izquierda para la tercera.

```
for contenido in [Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    linea = [f"{contenido[0]:<{max_ancho[0]}}",
             f"{contenido[1]:^{max_ancho[1]}}",
             f"{contenido[2]:>{max_ancho[2]}}"]
    print(' '.join(linea))
```

Si quieres separar más las columnas, es cosa de usar un string más ancho en el `join`, como

```
print('    '.join(linea))
```

#### Demo

```
Cabecera=["Nombre","Apellidos","DNI"]
Lista3=["María del Carmen","Perez Rivas","00000000A"]
Lista4=["Raquel","Gonzalez Perez","00000000B"]
Lista5=["Juan Francisco","Luis Hernandez","00000000C"]
Lista6=["Francisco","Gomez Palenzuela","00000000D"]

max_ancho = [0] * len(Cabecera)
for contenido in [Cabecera, Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    for idx in range(len(contenido)):
        max_ancho[idx] = max(max_ancho[idx], len(contenido[idx]))
print(max_ancho)

linea = [f"{Cabecera[0]:^{max_ancho[0]}}",
         f"{Cabecera[1]:^{max_ancho[1]}}",
         f"{Cabecera[2]:^{max_ancho[2]}}"]
print(' '.join(linea))
for contenido in [Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    linea = [f"{contenido[0]:<{max_ancho[0]}}",
             f"{contenido[1]:^{max_ancho[1]}}",
             f"{contenido[2]:>{max_ancho[2]}}"]
    print(' '.join(linea))
```

produce:

```
     Nombre         Apellidos        DNI   
María del Carmen   Perez Rivas    00000000A
Raquel            Gonzalez Perez  00000000B
Juan Francisco    Luis Hernandez  00000000C
Francisco        Gomez Palenzuela 00000000D

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: El OP no demostró haberlo intentado por su cuenta, por lo que estás respondiendo a una pregunta que no demostró esfuerzo por ser resuelta por parte del OP. Hay algo que no entiendo sobre las reglas?

Comment: Es un problema interesante y una respuesta educativa. Será de utilidad.

Comment: Perdón por no pasar antes por aquí, pero el trabajo me tiene absorbido. Esta solución me ha salvado la vida, era justo lo que pedía. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Simplificando un poco la solución de @CandidMoe podemos tener un menor código y que puedo servir para n cantidad de columnas, no daré mucha explicación ya que CandidMoe ya dio la suficiente.

```py
espacios = 0
for contenido in [Cabecera, Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    maximo = max(map(len, contenido))
    espacios = maximo if espacios<maximo else espacios

print(espacios)
```

Con esto obtenemos la longitud máxima del contenido de cada lista, para ello nos apoyamos de la función `map` la cual hará la labor de recorrer cada contenido y obtener su longitud con la función `len`, y luego obtenemos el máximo. Posteriormente asignaremos ese valor a la variable `espacios`, esta variable se irá actualizando con el valor máximo, para ello utilizamos un operador ternario el cual condiciona el valor.

Como dato adicional, si quieres una mayor separación entre las columna puedes agregarle un *margen* haciendo `espacios += 5`(o cualquier numero de espacios adicionales)

Ahora aplicaremos los caracteres de ajuste a las cabeceras

```py
Cabeceras = [f"{col:^{espacios}}" for col in Cabecera]
```

Ahora tenemos que aplicar estos operadores al *cuerpo* del texto. Dado que la primera columna debe ir alineada a la izquierda, haremos esa excepción.

```py
cuerpo = [] #aqui se almacenará el resultado

for line in [Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    row1 = f"{line[0]:<{espacios}}" #alineamos la primera columna a la izquierda

    #alineamos las demás filas al centro
    fila = [row1]+[f"{row:^{espacios}}" for row in line[1:]]
    fila[-1] +='\n' #agregamos un salto de línea en el ultimo dato

    cuerpo.append(fila) #agregamos a la lista cuerpo
```

Aquí he alineado todas las columnas al centro, exceptuando la primer, esto lo he hecho pensando en más columnas de las especificadas. Sin embargo en tu caso la ultima columna debe estar alineada a la derecha, para eso hacemos lo mismo que con la primera fila. Si  lo deseas alineado a la derecha, podemos hacer esto:

```py
cuerpo = []

for line in [Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]:
    row1 = f"{line[0]:<{espacios}}" #alineamos a la izquierda
    final_row = f"{line[-1]:>{espacios}}" #alineamos la ultimma a la derecha

    #las demás las alineamos al centr
    fila = [row1]+[f"{row:^{espacios}}" for row in line[1:-1]+[final_row]]
    fila[-1] +='\n'
    
    cuerpo.append(fila)
```

Con esto ya tenemos todo y solo nos faltaría escribir el archivo, para esto utilizaremos el método `join()` y algunas expresiones generadoras

```py
with open("archivo.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("".join(Cabeceras)+'\n')
    f.writelines("".join(line) for line in cuerpo)
```

Esto sirve para cualquier cantidad de columnas que tengas :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, al final me decanté por la de Candid Moe, pero todas me han servido y he aprendido con ellas^^

Comment: No te preocupes, es una buena respuesta y lo bueno es que resolviste tu problema :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo en unas pocas lineas

- Primero obtenemos la cantidad máxima de caracteres por cada columna, en eso podemos ayudarnos de `zip`, toma una serie de listas y las une, por ejemplo:

  ```py
  >>> list(zip(['a','b'], ['c','d']))
  [('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
  ```

  Y sobre ese resultado obtenemos las longitudes máximas por columna con `map`

  ```py
  # max_len, regresa la longitud máxima, ejemplo:
  # >>> max_len( ('ab', 'abc','a') )
  # 3
  map(max_len, zip(*data))
  ```
- Imprimimos cada renglón pero en tu archivo, `print` puede mandar todo el flujo de datos a tu archivo en vez de hacer varias llamaras `file.write`

### Implementación:

```py
data = [Lista3, Lista4, Lista5, Lista6]
def max_len(column): return max(map(len, column))


name_len, last_name_len, dni_len = map(max_len, zip(Cabecera,*data))

h_name, h_last_name, h_dni = Cabecera

print(
    f'{h_name:^{name_len}} {h_last_name:^{last_name_len}} {h_dni:^{dni_len}}',
    *[f'{name:{name_len}} {last_name:^{last_name_len}} {dni:^{dni_len}}'
      for name, last_name, dni in data],
    sep="\n", file=open('fichero.txt', 'w'))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias^^ al final me decanté por la respuesta de Candid Moe, pero la tuya también me fue de utilidad ^^

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la sintaxys de formateo de string tal como lo indica la [documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings). Esto lo consigues definiendo la cantidad de caracteres que debe usar un campo determinado y se rellenará hasta este valor.

El valor del relleno lo puedes definir arbitrariamente o contar los caracteres para el string más grande y agregarle un margen de diferencia.

```
lines = [
    ["Nombre","Apellidos","DNI"],
    ["María del Carmen","Perez Rivas","00000000A"],
    ["Raquel","Gonzalez Perez","00000000B"],
    ["Juan Francisco","Luis Hernandez","00000000C"],
    ["Francisco","Gomez Palenzuela","00000000D"]
]
f = open("./file.txt", "a")
for line in lines:
    f.write('{:28} {:^28s} {:^28s}\n'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2]))
f.close()
```

Más allá del código, la magia está en la siguiente linea.

```
f.write('{:28} {:^28s} {:^28s}\n'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2]))
```

Comment: y si se tiene más columnas, se tiene que añadir manualmente cada columna?

Comment: La pregunta no solicita columnas dinámicas, pero si es el caso el formato del string se puede construir fácilmente y la documentación especifica que ````.format()```` puede extraer las variables de una lista anteponiendo un * antes de la variable````.format(*line)````.
En ese caso puedes construir tu formato y la asignación de variables de forma dinámica gracia a listas sin una mayor complejidad.

Comment: El OP pide columnas centradas y también ajustadas por la derecha. Esta respuesta no satisface dichos requerimientos.

Comment: Gracias por la acotación, me salté esa parte. Para centrar solo es necesario encapsular el tamaño definido en el formato entre los caracteres ````^```` y ````s````. He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he probado varias y todas me servían pero al final me decanté por la de Candid Moe, pero como digo todas me han servido y he aprendido con ellas^^